# How do I handle an `err_connection_refused` HTTP error in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I want show the user a message if the HTTP request has  an `err_connection_refused` error. I am getting this error because the server is disconnected.

```js
http.get().subscribe(
    (response) => {

    },
    error => {
        // some  code to know error is err_connection_refused
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the error at the service level using the following RxJS 6 code:

```
http.get<YourType>().pipe(
  map(result=>{
    // do something here, such as accessing local storage, stopping a spinner...etc.
    return result;
  }),
  catchError(err => {
     return of (new YourType({}));
    // or you can return throwError(err);
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach you want. Just look at the err object in the console and see what the status is for connection refused:

```
http.get().pipe(
  // here we can stop the error being thrown for certain error responses
  catchError(err: HttpErrorResponse => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err.status == 404) return of(null)
    else throwError(err)
  })
).subscribe(
    (response) => {
    },
    // if the error is thrown (or not caught if you do not use catchError) we hit this block
    error => {
        console.log(err.status)
        // some  code to know error is err_connection_refused
    }
);
```